# Read particular depth XML ELEMENTS using XmlReader in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader

I have an XML file with some nodes at different depths. I need a code to read only specific depth nodes but not all, and only by using XmlReader in C#.

Can someone help me in this?

Below is my XML structure. I want to read only "Depth2" nodes.

```
<Depth0>
    <Depth1>
        <Depth2/>
        <Depth2/>
        <Depth2/>
    </Depth1>
    <Depth1>
        <Depth2/>
        <Depth2/>
        <Depth2/>
    </Depth1>
    <Depth1>
        <Depth2/>
        <Depth2/>
        <Depth2/>
    </Depth1>
</Depth0>
```

Code:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("D:\\xyz.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Depth == 4 && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            XmlReader chnode = reader.ReadSubtree();
            AddItems(chnode);
        }
        else
            reader.MoveToElement();
       }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What have you looked up? Please also add an example of your xml

Comment: Hi Gilad Green,
Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Descendants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml").Root
                      .Descendants("Depth2");
```

It will find for you all the `Depth2` elements anywhere under the xml's `Root`

---

For an `XmlReader` way you can:

```
List<XmlNode> nodes = new List<XmlNode>();
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml"))
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Depth == 2 && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            XmlNode node = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, reader.Name, "");
            //Here I just added all the inner xml but you can do whatever you need
            node.InnerXml = reader.ReadInnerXml();

            nodes.Add(node);
        }
        reader.MoveToElement();
    }
}
```